# Eventlistener 'mousemove' is not triggered when I scroll down on the page even though my mouse is in a different position after scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

This is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
    document
        .getElementsByClassName('landingScreen')[0]
        .addEventListener('mousemove', this.updateDisplay, false);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.isScrolling);

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (window.scrollY < 200) {
            this.setState({ opacity: 1 });
        }
    }, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document
        .getElementsByClassName('landingScreen')[0]
        .removeEventListener('mousemove', this.updateDisplay, false);
}

updateDisplay = event => {
    const procentWidth = Math.round((event.pageX / this.state.width) * 100) - 50;
    const procentHeight = Math.round((event.pageY / this.state.height) * 100 - 50);
    const transform = `skew(${procentWidth / 5}deg,${procentHeight / 5}deg)`;
    const textShadow = `${procentWidth / 1}px ${procentHeight / 1}px #5BDC94`;
    const textShadow1 = `${procentWidth / 1}px ${procentHeight / 1}px #EDF5E0`;
    const transform1 = `skew(${-procentWidth / 5}deg,${-procentHeight / 5}deg)`;
    this.setState({ transform, textShadow, textShadow1, transform1 });
};

isScrolling = event => {
    console.log(event);
    if (window.scrollY >= 200) {
        this.setState({ opacity: 0 });
    }
    if (window.scrollY <= 200) {
        this.setState({ opacity: 1 });
    }
};
```

I trigger a transform skew based on where my mouse is and it works fine when I move around my cursor but when I scroll and therefore my cursor changes position the 'mousemove' is not triggered. I tried to add a eventlistener for scroll but there I can't access these values event.pageX and event.pageY. Do you guys have any trick to trigger a 'mousemove' event after scrolling?

Comment: Let's assume you are sleeping in your bed. The average orbital speed of Earth is 107200 km/h. Do you consider yourself to be on the move? The cursor is considered to be moving when it's position is changed _relative_ to the viewport. When the page is scrolled that position doesn't change.

Comment: What he said ^ 
So basically you'll have to record the position whenever the mouse moves,then use the last position combined with the info in the scroll event do do your stuff